# Why did my ubuntu 23.04 install fail?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

ive been trying to install ubuntu alongside windows 11 for days now. started with 22.04 to no avail, so i tried 23.04, same issue. ryzen 7 3700x 8-core, RTX 3060 12gb

```
grub to /boot/efi.
Sep 24 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.2292[5928]:                 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Sep 24 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.2292[5928]:       
grub-install: warning: Internal error.
Sep 24 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.2292[5928]:            
grub-install: error: 
failed to register the EFI boot entry: Operation not permitted.
Sep 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.2292[5928]:                 
Sep 24 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.2292[5928]:         
Sep 24 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_log.2292[5928]: Stderr: ''
Sep 24 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_event.2292[2292]:   
executing curtin install curthooks step
Sep 24 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_event.2292[2292]: 
installing system
Sep 24 11:56:59 ubuntu subiquity_event.2292[2292]:
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296838/grub-install-error-failed-to-register-the-efi-boot-entry-operation-not-permitt  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298381/lubuntu-20-10-failed-to-register-the-efi-boot-entry-operation-not-permitted or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294984/grub-install-fails-on-ubuntu-20-04-1  Basically: uou have fast boot active.